# Unresolved token, unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, clr, unresolved-external

I'm getting these mistakes shown below. How can I fix them?

> Transporter.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0003E1) "public: __thiscall FTP::FTP(void)" (??0FTP@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __clrcall Transporter::Transporter(void)" (??0Transporter@@$$FQ$AAM@XZ)
>   1>Transporter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall FTP::FTP(void)" (??0FTP@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __clrcall Transporter::Transporter(void)" (??0Transporter@@$$FQ$AAM@XZ)

Comment: Make sure your FTP library is linked properly

Comment: I've added the lib file in project options.. But still get these errors

Comment: I feel you are on VS IDE, have you added library path ?

Comment: Yes, in Additional Library Directories in Linker-General

Comment: @user2071019 only additional directories, or did you actually add the `.lib` to input?

Comment: Sure in Linker-Input-Additional Depencies

Comment: The reason for that is that you are not linking the proper libraries.

Comment: Well, I've used it in another project and everything was ok. Maybe something is wrong because this is CLR project and I'm Marshalling C++ unmanaged class? Actually wrapping to managed C++

Comment: @user2071019 Did you define `FTP::FTP`? can you show your code?

Comment: What do you mean? Do I have FTP() constructor in class FTP? If so - yes.